# Components render multiple times - multiple fetch functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component renders 4 times and it seems to be caused by fetching and multiple setState functions. How can I make it use just one setState() including all fetched data?

I have already tried to create one function instead of one, create three variables to store fetch results and pass them to setState but it did not help me.
Thanks in advance!

````
class DuelList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        duels: [],
        users: [],
        datasets: []
    };

    fetchDuels = () => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    duels: res.data
                });
            });
    };

    fetchUsers = () => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    users: res.data
                });
            });
    };

    fetchDatasets = () => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    datasets: res.data
                });
            });
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchDuels();
        this.fetchUsers();
        this.fetchDatasets();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Duels data={this.state.duels}/> <br/>
                <h2> Add duel </h2>
                <AddDuelForm users={this.state.users} datasets={this.state.datasets} requestType="post" articleID={null}
                             btnText="Challenge"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DuelList;```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to group and resolve all the promises together:

```
    fetchDuels = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
    };

    fetchUsers = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
    };

    fetchDatasets = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        const promises = [this.fetchDuels(), this.fetchUsers(), this.fetchDatasets()];

        Promise.all(promises).then(([ duelsReponse, usersResponse, datasetsReponse ]) => {
            this.setState({ duels: duelsReponse.data, users: usersReponse.data, datasets: datasetsResponse.data });
        });
    }
```

This way, you reduce the number `setState` calls.

Comment: thanks! that has helped a bit but still the components renders twice, what should be my next step?

Comment: it will always render at least twice, because your doing asynchronous calls.  it will render with no data, and then again when data arrives.

Comment: ok, but what is the approach when one fetch function url depends on another fetch function response?

Comment: then, you need to chain promises.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Promise.all` and setState once all the apis resulted in success response like

```
class DuelList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        duels: [],
        users: [],
        datasets: []
    };

    fetchDuels = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})

    };

    fetchUsers = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})

    };

    fetchDatasets = () => {
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/",
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})

    };


    componentDidMount() {
        Promise.all([this.fetchDuels(), this.fetchUsers(), this.fetchDatasets()]).then(([duels, users, datasets]) => {
            this.setState({
                 duels,
                 users,
                 datasets
            })
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Duels data={this.state.duels}/> <br/>
                <h2> Add duel </h2>
                <AddDuelForm users={this.state.users} datasets={this.state.datasets} requestType="post" articleID={null}
                             btnText="Challenge"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DuelList;
```